# List only the most recent file for every month in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, sas

I am trying to find a way to parse several hundreds XLS files; these contain monthly reports and are stored in subdirectories. In some cases, there are several reports for a month due to errors in the initial XLS file that were later corrected. I am working in a windows environment. 
I need to import these files in SAS to do analysis; I cannot use any other tool than SAS and basic windows shell (maybe powershell).

The name of the files contain information about the date it was generated in, so that I can identify re-runs from the names only. An example of the content of a directory would be like:

```
rep1_02012016.xls
rep1_02112016.xls #this would be a rerun on feb 11 if feb 1's report contains an error
rep1_03012016.xls
rep1_04012016.xls
```

My idea is to pipe the output of a shell command to SAS so that I know which files to read. I can't find a way to get a single file for each month, filtering all but the most recent one for every month. So I would get one for Feb, one for Mar, one for Apr, and so on.
Any pointer would be welcome.

Comment: Your question lacks multiple details. Are the files grouped in subdirectories per year? Do you want results by year, or all files in the same report? Is the name format _always_ XXXX_MMDDYYYY.xls or the prefix may have different length? Is the prefix _always_ delimited by underscore? If you don't post precise questions you may not get precise answers...

Comment: ... and your comment in the example is wrong: `this would be a rerun on feb 11 if feb 1's report contains an error`, but there is _not_ a report on feb 1's, just on feb 2's. **`:/`**

Comment: @aacini:I've re-installed what I believe is a typo - the first filename should include `02012016` not `02021916`

Comment: @Magoo: It should be obvious that the purpose of my comments is that the OP realize that he/she should put more detail and attention when writting the questions...

Comment: @aacini, it was obviously a typo. I don't get your acrimony, the file structure i exemplified (apart from the typo, for which I am, of course, terribly sorry) is exactly what i have in my folder. I see no point in trying to find problems to solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like (untested):

```
data with_dates;
   set all_files;
   * Assume the date always starts at position 6 and is 8 chars long;
   date = input(substr(filename, 6, 8), mmddyy8.);
   * Get the month and year from the date;
   month = month(date);
   year = year(date);
run;

* Sort into monthly groups with the records in date otder within each group;
proc sort data=with_dates out=with_dates_sorted;
   by year month date;
run;

* Keep only the last file from each monthly group;
data last_per_month_only;
   set with_dates_sorted;
   by year month;
   if last.month;
run;
```

That should be pretty close, though note it makes lots of assumptions about the format of your filenames - you might want to split the filename on the underscore, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with powershell, this assumes that your reports are uniformly named as the filenames are being used to determine the dates with a substring:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem .\path\to\dir
$months = @("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12")

$output = @()

foreach ($m in $months) {
  $f = $files.name | Where-Object { $_.substring(5,2) -eq $m }
  if ($f.count -gt 1) {
    $f = ($f | Sort-Object -Descending)[0]
  }
  $output += $f
}

Write-Host $output
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process the files, store the last one of each month in "file" array
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *.xls') do (
   set "fdate=%%b"
   set "file[!fdate:~0,2!]=%%a_%%b"
)

rem Show the result
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set file[') do echo %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

For a batch file version

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure source folder
    set "rootPath=x:\somewhere"

    rem If the source folder can be reached
    pushd "%rootPath%" && (

        rem Prepare a temporary file reference
        for %%t in ("%temp%\%random%%random%%random%%random%.tmp") do (

            rem Prepare a list of files in reverse name order
            >"%%~ft" ((for /r "." %%a in (rep1_*.xls) do @echo(%%~na %%~fa)|sort /r)

            rem For each month retrieve the first file in the list 
            for %%m in (
                01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
            ) do for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('
                findstr /i "rep1_%%m" "%%~ft" ^| cmd /e /v /c"set /p.=&(echo(!.!)"
            ') do if not "%%~b"=="" (echo(%%b)

        rem Remove the temporary file
        ) & del /q "%%~ft"

        rem Return to previous active directory
        popd
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
:: remove variables starting $ which shouldn't exist - make sure
For %%b IN ($) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

:: set $yyyymm50-dd for each date where a file exists.
FOR /f "tokens=2delims=_." %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\rep1_*.xls" '
 ) DO (
 SET "gendate=%%a"
 SET /a gendate=!gendate:~-4!!gendate:~0,2!50 -1!gendate:~2,2!+100
 SET "$!gendate!=%%a"
)

:: Now read each set $ value in date-order of YYMM, reverse-dd
SET prevdate=0
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=$=" %%a IN ('set $') DO (
 SET /a gendate=%%a
 IF "!prevdate!" neq "!gendate:~0,6!" (
  SET /a prevdate=%%a/100
  ECHO rep1_%%b.xls
 )
)


GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

First step is to acquire the date portion from the filename, restring it as yyyymmXX where XX=50-dd. This is accomplished by inserting a constant `50`, adding 100 and subtracting `1` strung with the day number to allow for batch's idea that a string starting `0` (like `08`) is octal, not decimal.

The result is that the $variable with a later date in the month will have a smaller number on the "dd" position than one earlier in the month, and hence be listed earlier in the `set` list. The `$number` is then assigned the original date string from the filename.

All that's then required is to detect when $yyyymm changes in a `set` list for $vars. As soon as that string changes, a new month has been detected and the filename can be reconstructed. This also sets a new `prevdate` by conveniently lopping off the final 2 digits of `gendate` by dividing by 100.